# While loading images dynamically from folder, two images appear with dots

Tags: php, html, image

I'm trying to load images from a folder on the local server.
[image]

But there are only the 3 images that appear correctly in the folder.

```
<table class="table">
    <?php 
    $dir  = '../images/slideshow';
    $file_display = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

    if (file_exists($dir) == false) {
        echo 'Directory \''. $dir. '\' not found!';
    } else {
        $dir_contents = scandir($dir);

        foreach ($dir_contents as $file) {
            $ex = explode('.', $file);
            $file_type = strtolower(end($ex));

            ?>
            <tr>
            <td><img alt="<?php echo $file?>" width="64px" height="64px" src="<?php echo $dir."/".$file?>">
            <td class="td" style="text-align: center;"><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?action=delete&id=".$row["id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-danger" >Delete</a><?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

EDIT:
I was able to fix this by changing the above code to the following...

```
<table class="table">
    <?php 
    $dir  = '../images/slideshow';
    $file_display = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

    if (file_exists($dir) == false) {
        echo 'Directory \''. $dir. '\' not found!';
    } else {
        $dir_contents = scandir($dir);
        $file_display = array(
                'jpg',
                'jpeg',
                'png',
                'gif'
        );

        foreach ($dir_contents as $file) {
            $ex = explode('.', $file);
            $file_type = strtolower(end($ex));
            if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' && in_array($file_type, $file_display) == true) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                <td><img alt="<?php echo $file?>" width="64px" height="64px" src="<?php echo $dir."/".$file?>">
                <td class="td" style="text-align: center;"><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?action=delete&id=".$row["id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-danger" >Delete</a><?php
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Just checking the file extensions.

Comment: check your image name and path of the folder used in that two images....

Comment: use developer tools for check image path. right click-> Inspect Element

Comment: Also Post PHP code

Comment: do your image file names have spaces in them? If so, remove the spaces

Comment: where is your code

Comment: This is what the inspect element looks like? <img alt=".." width="64px" height="64px" src="../images/slideshow/..">

Comment: Those are for sure your `.` and `..` directories, since you get ALL files/folders using `scandir` and you're not checking the files' extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` and `..` define the current dir and the parent dir from your current path. `scandir` fetches all files and folders in your path, so those are displayed as images as well, since you never check for a valid file extension (defined in your `$file_display`). To get rid of `.` and `..` you can use

`$dir_contents = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('.', '..'))`